# How to handle no data incoming through a Port to NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

```
Server.js   
var backEndNodeServer = require('http').createServer(test).listen(8080);                
function test (req, res) {
console.log("Server: incoming message from 8080");
req.on(//get data received from 8080 );
{ doSomething(); }
res.end(); }
```

a jar file sends me a String into the handler "test" that I work on in req.on. How do I handle the case when the jar is down and it returns nothing and there is nothing in test? I want to be able to doSomething() when jar is down. currently it does not even go inside the handler "test".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timeout that runs if it takes too long for the request to be made.

```
var incomingTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
  console.error('request not received');
}, 60 * 1000); // 60s
```

in your request handler, clear the timeout:

```
clearTimeout(incomingTimeout);
```

Comment: how do I add timeout on backEndNodeServer ?